# How can I return the result of celery task to the client in Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, celery

I making the DB searching web application. I made the progress-bar with celery + ajax + Django. However, I don't know how to return the results of celery task to the client. I want to show the results in the template.

I know that celery has the `.get()` methods for returning a result. How can I use them with ajax?

I don't know how to code celery-python for this work. Do I have to use celery mysql as a backend? Please share some ideas or recommend other things.

Comment: There are some database back ends are available for django-celery to store your periodic tasks. see this link https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat

Comment: So user starts multiple tasks and you want to show which % was finished by making AJAX query? If users starts only one tasks than it is just 0% or 100%.

Comment: @Raz User can starts only one task at a time ! So, I'm thinking of the way to show the result of the task !

Comment: @Darshan Thank you!!

Comment: @DaWoonJung does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Darshan Yeah , I solved it but another method. Thank you for your suggestion, I'm newly know about database backends Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve it @DaWoonJung?